# Executing all queries in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a below table structure - QueryDetails in sql server

```
 AccountNo   TableName    ColumnName     ColumnValue   Query
 1           account        balance          123       update account set balance = 123 where AccountNo = 1
 2           loan           emi             1000       update loan set emi = 1000 where AccountNo = 2
```

I need a syntax or query to execute all the sql queries in the column Query, instead of selecting the column query and executing it manually.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the column value and executing with dynamic SQL? Are you using Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server? You have tags for both products.

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to be forced to use dynamic here I would do something like this so you don't have to use a cursor.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + Query + ';'
from YourTable

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Please note, I do not condone storing queries like this in a table. And I don't condone running them. It is potentially vulnerable to sql injection.

Of if you are trying to build up the query based on the data in the table it might be something like this. Please note this assume that every column being updated is a number and the values in the ColumnValue column are numbers.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'Update ' + QUOTENAME(TableName) + ' set ' QUOTENAME(ColumnName) + ' = ' + convert(varchar(10), ColumnValue) + ' where AccountNo = ' + convert(varchar(10), AccountNo)
from YourTable

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Interesting take on it. I like it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SQL Server way using a cursor...

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT Query FROM QueryDetails 

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sql

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    exec(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sql
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all queries using STUFF function and then execute it

Assuming below sample table.

```
create table #t
(
    AccountNo int,
    TableName varchar(100),
    Query varchar(max)
)

insert into #t values 
(1, 'account', 'update account set balance = 123 where AccountNo = 1'),
(2, 'loan', 'update loan set emi = 1000 where AccountNo = 2')
```

You can execute all queries as:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';' + Query
              FROM #t
              ORDER BY Query
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Output])
print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

`@sql` will contain statement like this:

```
update account set balance = 123 where AccountNo = 1;update loan set emi = 1000 where AccountNo = 2
```